# Why does Response.Redirect("") Return an Error in One Test Environment and Not Another?

Tags: asp.net, iis, response.redirect

We're trying to figure out how to fix a bug found in 3rd party IV&V testing, which we can't recreate in our internal test environment.

We've determined that the bug is caused by a URL value being inadvertently set to an empty string ("") before attempting to redirect to it. Hence, we're trying to execute Response.Redirect("").

In the external test environment, this line of code results in the following error:

```
Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
```

In the internal test environment, the current page is simply reloaded.

The servers are virtually identical - the internal test server has the same physical hardware as the external server, and is even running a copy of a virtual image of the external server. Hence, all Windows and IIS settings *should* be identical.

Is there a physical networking, load balancing or other environmental issue that could cause this kind of discrepancy?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Are you sure it's a server problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would use Fiddler to take a look at the HTTP response from the server and make sure they are exactly the same.  When you've done that, you know it's a client-side or environment issue.  Next...

What is the URL in the address bar for the two browsers?  Better yet... in IE right click on the page and look at the Properites.  What are you *really* seeing here?  On my local system testing Response.Redirect("") I get something like this: "res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm#http://localhost/test.aspx"   DNSERROR!  Hmmmm... interesting!

Also, consider what happens in the following situation:
http://somelanname

...in an environment where "somelanname" is the name of a resource on your local intranet... and then what happens when you try to access that URL when it doesn't exist.  I think you are seeing the same thing here.